# Number of possible subsets according to restriction.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, combinations

There is a set $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. We want to choose two subsets $P$ and $Q$ (they can be same also) such that $n(P) \geq n(Q)$. Find number of ways of doing so.

I first assigned cardinality of $P$ as $8$ then cardinality of $Q$ can be from $0$ to $8$. Therefore, number of ways for this is $8C8(8C0+8C1+8C2+ \ldots +8C8)$. Continuing in same way, I can generalise that the number of ways is $(\Sigma_{i=n}^{8}[8Ci]\Sigma_{j=0}^{i-1}[8Cj])$. How to simplify further?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^8$ subsets and thus $2^{16}$ pairs of subsets. Roughly half of these pairs, that is, $2^{15}$, have $|P|\ge|Q|$, but to this we have to add half the number of pairs with $|P|=|Q|$. These are in bijection with the number of ways of choosing $8$ from $16$ elements (make two copies of the set, choose the elements in $P$ in one copy and the elements of $\overline Q$ in the other, for a total of $|P|+8-|Q|=8$), of which there are $\binom{16}8$. Thus there are

$$
2^{15}+\frac12\binom{16}8=39203
$$

pairs with $|P|\ge|Q|$.

Comment: Shouldnt we add $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 16C8$

Comment: @h-squared: Indeed, thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: How did u say that half of these have P>Q

Comment: @dhaneshvijay: We have either $|P|\lt|Q|$, $|P|=|Q|$ or $|P|\gt|Q|$. By symmetry, $|P|\lt|Q|$ as often as $|P|\gt|Q|$. So if we take half of all cases, we have all of $|P|\gt|Q|$ and half of $|P|=|Q|$, so we need to add another half of $|P|=|Q|$ to get $|P|\ge|Q|$.